# Каталог телефонов

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Подскажите, как реализовать следующий проект, чтобы в приложение были таблицы с телефонами, где вся информация о телефонах бралась с сайта. То есть в каждой ячейке таблицы картинка, цена и название.

Comment: Сайт-API-XML/JSON-парсер-тэйблвью.

Comment: Мне кажется, [что-то подобное](http://hashcode.ru/questions/131228/каталог-товаров) уже было, причем после этого вы [задали](http://hashcode.ru/questions/130500/парсер-html-кода) [ещё](http://hashcode.ru/questions/131517/загрузка-изображения) [ряд](http://hashcode.ru/questions/132601/переход-в-uinavigationcontroller) [более конкретных](http://hashcode.ru/questions/131179/загрузка-картинки-по-ссылке-в-uiimageview) [вопросов](http://hashcode.ru/questions/130722/парсинг-цен), *получив на них ответы*. Что вы ожидаете услышать на этот раз?

Comment: Ждет, наверное, когда же за него напишут это приложение...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Спланировать на бумаге, что, как, где и когда будет работать. То есть разбить задачу на состаляющие, эти составляющие станут в будующем классами. К примеру парсер, это у вас будет отдельный класс, которыый все будет красиво раскладывать по полочкам что надо, а что не надо.
2. Организовать хранение данных для просмотра каталога в оффлайн режиме, как вы это реализуете зависит от вас и вообще этот пункт опциональный.
3. Разобраться с изображениями в тэйблвью, то есть понять как работает кэширование изображений, расспаралелить приложение, асинхронная загрузка, так как сразу вы не сможете отобразить в таблице кукуеву тучу картинок, таблица зависнет.
4. Понять как ре-использовать ячейки таблицы таким образом что бы не проиходило наложения UILabel друг на друга.

И вот когда у вас будет подробный план и четкое ТЗ тогда вы уже мосете присесть к разроботке самого приложения, хорошо спланированный ход работы обезовасит вас от потери времени и нервов.

Comment: Я не совсем про это!Но ответ хороший)Дело в том что на сайте не сразу все телефоны открываются,там несколько страниц по 8 телефонов на каждой.У меня возникла проблема,как пропарсить второй телефон.И как пропарсить телефоны со второй страницы.

Comment: @Sergey4590 об этой вашей проблеме мы должны были сами догадаться?

Comment: Кхм, как я понимаю вы составили план, если нет то пусть будет на вашей совести, смотрим документацию от яндекс маркета(я смотрю пока только контентный API), тут необходимо получить ключ авторизации, а далее прочитав еще немного доки, можно заметить что нам дают API в двух форматах JSON/XML выбираем что ближе к телу и стем работаем, при использовании, скажем так нативного API упростит нам жизнь. Ваш вариант со скачиванием контента в строку и дальнейший поиск по строке я считаю не приемлимым, так как нативный API сбережет время и нервы.

Comment: Не совсем!Мне нужно парсить сайт написанный на bitrix. Первый телефон я парсю без проблем как ко второму подобраться хз. И как на вторую страницу зайти то хз.

Comment: *рука-лицо-Х2* Нельзя просто так взять и опарсить сайт! Почему не хотите заюзать API, вы хотите сберечь время или нервы или все сразу да еще и бабла получить??? А вот если уберут с сайта те тэги из которых вы дергаете цену???

Comment: Я в этом не разбераюсь!Но и все же у сайта написанного на bitrixe есть API?

Comment: В чем вы не разбираетесь? Вы с какого сайта пытаетесь вырвать контент??? 
Так на всякий случай почитать стоит на досуге http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Интерфейс_программирования_приложений

Comment: С сайта написанного на bitrix'e

Comment: сылку на сайт можно?